# Asymptotic behavior of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I am trying to analyze the sequence $g(n)$, defined as follows:

- $g(1)=0$
- $g(2)=1$
- For $n\geq 2$, $g(n+1)=g(n)\left(1+\displaystyle{\frac{n}{n-1}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}\right)$.

A computational experiment suggests that, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\displaystyle{\frac{g(n)}{n}}$ approaches a constant of $\approx 0.758097$, but I don't know how to prove it.  How would you do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $\displaystyle h(n) = 1-\frac1n+\ln\biggl( 1+\frac1n \biggr)$, so that
\begin{align*}
g(n+1) &= \prod_{k=2}^n \biggl( 1+\frac k{k-1}\ln\frac{k+1}k \biggr) \\
&= \prod_{k=2}^n \biggl( \frac k{k-1}h(k) \biggr) = \prod_{k=2}^n \frac k{k-1} \prod_{k=2}^n h(k) = n \prod_{k=2}^n h(k).
\end{align*}
But from the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$, we see that $h(n) \displaystyle = 1+O\biggl( \frac1{n^2} \biggr)$, and so this last product converges as $n\to\infty$. Indeed this equation implies
$$
g(n) = n \prod_{k=2}^\infty h(k)+O(1)
$$
where this infinite product is indeed approximately $0.75809696$, accurate to that many decimal places (rounded).

Comment: If $C$ denotes your constant then $$
g(n) \sim Cn\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{7}{{24n^2 }} - \frac{5}{{48n^3 }} - \frac{{313}}{{5760n^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary could you explain how you got these? Are there some standard tools to find this?

Comment: @DiegoSantos I posted an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I shall derive a complete asymptotic expansion. Let
$$
C := \prod\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right)} = 0.758096959930697113026\ldots
$$
and
$$
f(n) := \left[ {\prod\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right)} } \right]^{ - 1} 
$$
for any $n\ge 1$. Then, for $n \ge 3$,
\begin{align*}
g(n) & = \prod\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 1} {\left( {1 + \frac{k}{{k - 1}}\log \left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{k}} \right)} \right)}  = \prod\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 1} {\frac{k}{{k - 1}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right)} 
\\ & = (n-1)\prod\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 1} {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right)}  = C \cdot (n-1) \cdot f(n).
\end{align*}
Now
\begin{align*}
f(n) & = \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\log\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)} \right)} } \right) = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{m = 2}^\infty  {(-1)^m\frac{{a_m }}{{m!}}\frac{1}{{k^m }}} } } \right)
\\ & = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{m = 2}^\infty  {(-1)^m\frac{{a_m }}{{m!}}\sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^m }}} } } \right) = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{m = 2}^\infty  {(-1)^m\frac{{a_m }}{{m!}}\zeta (m,n)} } \right),
\end{align*}
where the sequence $a_m$ is [$\mathrm{A}331559$](https://oeis.org/A331559) in the OEIS, and $\zeta(m,n)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.i). Now for each fixed $m$,
$$
\zeta (m,n) \sim \frac{1}{{m - 1}}\frac{1}{{n^{m - 1} }} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{n^m }} + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{B_k }}{{k!}}\frac{{(m)_{k - 1} }}{{n^{m + k - 1} }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ (cf. [$(25.11.43)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E43)). Here $B_k$ denotes the [Bernoulli numbers](https://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2#i) and $(m)_k$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.iii). Substitution and re-arrangement then gives
$$
\sum\limits_{m = 2}^\infty  {(-1)^m\frac{{a_m }}{{m!}}\zeta (m,n)}  \sim \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{b_m }}{{n^m }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, where $b_1  = \frac{1}{2}$, $b_2  = \frac{1}{12}$ and
$$
b_m  = (-1)^{m+1}\frac{{a_{m + 1} }}{{m(m + 1)!}} + (-1)^{m}\frac{1}{2}\frac{{a_m }}{{m!}} + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{m - 1} {(-1)^{m-k+1}\frac{{B_k \, a_{m - k + 1} }}{{k!(m - k + 1)!}}(m - k + 1)_{k - 1} } ,
$$
for $m\ge 3$. Exponentiation of this asymptotic expansion then yields
$$
g(n) \sim C \cdot (n-1) \cdot \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_m }}{{n^m }}}  = C \cdot (n-1)\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{5}{{24n^2 }} + \frac{5}{{48n^3 }} + \frac{{287}}{{5760n^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, where $c_0=1$ and
$$
c_m  = \frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {kb_k c_{m - k} } 
$$
for $m\ge 1$. A more natural form is
$$
g(n) \sim C \cdot n \cdot \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{d_m }}{{n^m }}}  = C \cdot n\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{7}{{24n^2 }} - \frac{5}{{48n^3 }} - \frac{{313}}{{5760n^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, where $d_0=1$ and
$$
d_m  = c_m  - c_{m - 1} 
$$
for $m\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Some loose bounds:
$$\dfrac{g(n+1)}{g(2)} = \prod_{k=2}^n\dfrac{g(k+1)}{g(k)} = \prod_{k=2}^n\left(1 + \dfrac{k}{k-1}\ln\frac{k+1}{k}\right)< \prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac 1k\right)^{\frac{k}{k-1}}$$
and also:
$$g(n+1)<g(2)\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k-1}\right) =  n$$ by using $\ln(1+x)<x$ and by using $\dfrac{x}{1+x}<\ln x:$
$$g(n+1) > \prod_{k=2}^n\left(1 + \dfrac{k}{k^2-1}\right)>\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k}\right) = \dfrac{n+1}{2}.$$ I don't know if the infinite products have closed form in the limit though.